# What is a free element of a matroid?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, combinatorial-geometry, matroids

I have often read the term *free element* of a given matroid $M$. However, I could not find a proper defintion of what a free element actually is. I know what the free matroid is but free elements seem to be something else. I first thought that free elements are coloops. However, I have read sentences like "then $e$ must be a coloop or a free element of $M$" which suggests that coloops and free elements are not necessarily the same.

For example, free elements are mentioned in this paper on pages 4 and 11: [https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/LaminarMatroids_revised.pdf](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Eoxley/LaminarMatroids_revised.pdf)

I would appreciate if someone could give me a definition of a free element or/and provide an example of such an element in a certain matroid.

Comment: Can you give an example or a link, where you read (often) "free element" of a matroid?

Comment: @DietrichBurde For example in this paper on pages 4 and 11. https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/LaminarMatroids_revised.pdf

Comment: The notion of a [free matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Free_matroid) seems conventional enough, but that paper uses *free element* of a matroid briefly without defining it.  My guess would be that the papers authors expect their Readers to be familiar with a variety of specialized terms covered by the references cited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $e$ in $M$ is *free* if it is not a coloop(not all basis contain $e$) and if $e\in C$ circuit, then there is a basis $B$ such that $C=C(B,e)$, that is a spanning circuit.
For example, consider $M(C_n)=M(\{0,\cdots ,n-1\},\{\{i,(i+1)\pmod n\}\})$ the cycle matroid of a circuit with $n$ elements. There is just one circuit and it is spanning. For any edge $e$, there is a basis that does not contain $e$ (mainly $\{0,\cdots ,n-1\}\setminus e$), so every element is *free* there. 
Check the definition [here (Unbreakable Matroids)](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Eoxley/Unbreakable-Matroids_3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the example! This helped me a lot!